# Windows 7 x64 - Adjusting screen brightness is reversed

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, brightness, toshiba-laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a problem with adjusting screen brightness on Windows 7 x64.

If I change brightness with Nvidia control manager, it works correctly but if I change it with Windows, it is reversed. Pushing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> button increases brightness instead of decreasing. The same it is with windows adjust brightness settings.

I use Windows 7 x64, a graphic card GeForce GT M230 and a display driver Nvidia 314.07 on my laptop Toshiba Satellite a500-1c0.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and get into your BIOS. You may have options to adjust the operation of your Fn keys from there.

Comment: I already googled answers like this yours but I have minimum of options in BIOS. These options are missing and fast/normal boot option is missing as well.  
I have one more important information. If I boot to linux (ubuntu), keys work as expected. There is no brightness problem in linux.  
I have 32bit ubuntu. I think the problem is in 64bit version of OS.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Linux, just basic user operation :(..... Sorry